# XSL Links to pages

Tags: templates, xslt, href, apply-templates

I'm a novice in XSL, so excuse me if my question is too easy.

Look at code

```
<table class="foot_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="open_all">
            <a href="/shop/showall">show all</a>
            </div>
            </td>   
        <td>
<div id="producers_footer">
close
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So i have page showall.xsl. How can i connect xslt template with that page?
Because now my page (showall) is empty.
Can you show me some examples?

Comment: Sorry George, but could you elaborate and clarify your question. I've absolutely no idea what's your problem. You're showing HTML and ask about XSLT - where's the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure, but I think you are looking for a XSLT processor. An XSLT processor takes the source code (html in your case) and executes the showall.xslt on it and produces a new output.

Some references:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/08/30/xsltandhtml/index.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:XSLT_processors

Comment: thanks a lot. How can i understand what kind of xslt processor I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a free copy of Visual Studio Express 2012 and process the xslt and xml in there.